# Weird mouse scroll behaviour in emacs - iterm2 in LISP MODE

Tags: terminal, emacs, mouse, spacemacs

When I am in "lisp mode" scrolling with the mouse inserts loads of brackets. How do I change the behaviour from this to "scroll"?
I am using spacemacs via ssh iterm2

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in this case is the fact that terminal are reporting a bunch of things, one of these things are mouse position, and evil-cleverparens has additional bindings that cause the behaviour you're observing.

If `evil-cleverparens-use-additional-bindings` is not disabled, there is a [bunch of bindings](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-cleverparens/blob/8936d2edfca90d39c53e5217afd0bbb9273a82e5/evil-cleverparens.el#L2051-L2081) that are enabled and will cause your issue.

Using emacs `describe-key` you can see the following when moving mouse:

```
Describe the following key, mouse click, or menu item: ESC [ < 3 5 ; 1 ; 1 M-
```

There is an [issue on Github](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-cleverparens/issues/58#issuecomment-717415043) where this problem is discussed.

One way to fix this in spacemacs if you don't use these bindings, is like this:

```
(use-package evil-cleverparens
 :defer t
 :init
 (setq evil-cleverparens-use-additional-bindings nil))
```

You can also disable mouse reporting in iTerm.
[image]

NOTE: Terminals also report focus and it might cause [similar issues](https://superuser.com/questions/931873/o-and-i-appearing-on-iterm2-when-focus-lost). Again, using `describe-key` you can see it in action when terminal gets focus:

```
Describe the following key, mouse click, or menu item: ESC [ I-
```